# get child and subchild attribute value using ajax xpath and store in to variable

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

xml look like :-

```
 <childrens>
<child_1 entity_id="1" value="Root Catalog" parent_id="0">
<child_2 entity_id="2" value="Navigate" parent_id="1">
    <child_4 entity_id="4" value="Activities" parent_id="2">
        <child_10066 entity_id="10066" value="Physical1" parent_id="4">
            <child_10067 entity_id="10067" value="Cricket" parent_id="10066">
                <child_10068 entity_id="10068" value="One Day" parent_id="10067"/>
            </child_10067>
        </child_10066>
        <child_10069 entity_id="10069" value="Test2" parent_id="4"/>
        <child_10070 entity_id="10070" value="Test3" parent_id="4"/>
        <child_10071 entity_id="10071" value="Test4" parent_id="4"/>
        <child_10072 entity_id="10072" value="Test5" parent_id="4"/>
        <child_5 entity_id="5" value="Physical" parent_id="4"/>
        </child_4>
    <child_4331 entity_id="4331" value="Region" parent_id="2">
        <child_4332 entity_id="4332" value="Asia" parent_id="4331">
            <child_4333 entity_id="4333" value="Afghanistan" parent_id="4332">
                <child_4334 entity_id="4334" value="Balkh" parent_id="4333">
                    <child_4335 entity_id="4335" value="Mazar-e-Sharif" parent_id="4334"/>
                </child_4334>
                <child_4336 entity_id="4336" value="Herat" parent_id="4333">
                    <child_4337 entity_id="4337" value="Herat" parent_id="4336"/>
                </child_4336>
            </child_4333>
        </child_4332>
    </child_4331>
</child_2>
</child_1>
</childrens>
```

in above xml file i am try to get all Activities and Region Both in different variable.
with this tried.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var result_region='';
var node_region;
var comma_region='';
var activity;
var result_activity='';
var node_activity;
var comma_activity='';
var region;
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ 
                url: 'final.xml', 
                type:"get",
                async: false,
                success: function(xml) { 
                var xPath_region = '//child_4/*[@value]' + '/@value';
                var xPath_activity = '//child_4331/*[@value]' + '/@value';

                var iterator = xml.evaluate(xPath_region, xml.documentElement, null,
                        XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
                    var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
                    while (thisNode) {
                    node_region = thisNode.textContent;
                    thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
                        if(result_region.indexOf(node_region) == -1){
                                result_region += comma_region+node_region;
                                comma_region=',';
                }
            }

            var iterator = xml.evaluate(xPath_activity, xml.documentElement, null,
                        XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
                    var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
                    while (thisNode) {
                    node_activity = thisNode.textContent;
                    thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
                        if(result_activity.indexOf(node_activity) == -1){
                                result_activity += comma_activity+node_activity;
                                comma_activity=',';
                }
            }
            activity = result_region;
            region = result_activity;
            alert(activity);
            alert(region);
            },
            });
});
</script>
```

above code returned:-

```
var activity = "Physical1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5";
var region = "Asia";
```

its only return first level node b'coz i am try on xpath find `Child_4` i want all child and there child node.
like:-

```
var activity = "Physical1,Cricket,One Day,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5";
var region = "Asia,Afghanistan,Balkh,Mazar-e-Sharif,Herat,Herat";
```

how can i get all child and there child sub child value.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are quite close:
You have only to change the both xpaht expressions from:

```
var xPath_region = '//child_4/*[@value]' + '/@value';
var xPath_activity = '//child_4331/*[@value]' + '/@value';
```

to:

```
var xPath_region = '//child_4//*[@value]' + '/@value';
var xPath_activity = '//child_4331//*[@value]' + '/@value';
```

You have only selected direct child of child_4 wiht value attribute but you like to select all descendant of child_4 (`//child_4/descendant::*`) or short (`//child_4//*`)
Which will output the following regions:

```
 "Asia,Afghanistan,Balkh,Mazar-e-Sharif,Herat"
```

and activities:

```
"Physical1,Cricket,One Day,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5"
```